# Odd Behaviour: Missing Chapter Title in Footer, However the Page Number is Displayed

Tags: xetex, header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

### Problem Description

I’d like to create a footer style that would be displayed on all pages except for the page, where there is `\part` title and its verso page (this exception is not a problem, as it works). So I added the following code into the preamble:

```
\clearscrheadfoot
\lefoot{\pagemark\quad\textsc{\headmark}}
\rofoot{\textsc{\headmark}\quad\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
```

The actual problem is that on every odd page, only the page number is displayed and no chapter title. There is no problem with the footer on even pages.

I’d like to note that I use `xelatex` and currently I am trying out the KOMA-Script.

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[10pt, chapterprefix=false, twoside]{scrbook}

% Packages
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in, left=1in, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}            % For font definition
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}    % For headers and footers (must be loaded before `titlesec`); also, in KomaScript, this is used instead of `titleps`
\usepackage{titlesec}            % For custom paragraph style of headings
\usepackage{lipsum}              % For Lorem Ipsum

% Global font family
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

% Global paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Part title format
\titleformat{\part}{\Huge\scshape\bfseries\centering}{}{0em}{}%

% Chapter title format
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}% For starting a chapter without page break

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{0pt}\Large\scshape\bfseries\centering}
    {\thesection\enspace}{0pt}{}[\vspace{2pt}{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}%
    {0mm}% How much of \titlerule line to remove from left
    {8mm}% Before \titlerule
    {0mm}% After \titlerule

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% This is to get rid of the chapter number

% Headers and footers
\clearscrheadfoot
\lefoot{\pagemark\quad\textsc{\headmark}}
\rofoot{\textsc{\headmark}\quad\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
    \part*{Test Part}

    \chapter*{Test Chapter or Whatever}%
    \chaptermark{Test Chapter}%

    \lipsum[1-14]

    \chapter*{Another Chapter to test}%
    \chaptermark{Another Chapter}%

    \lipsum[15-21]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-Topic: With KOMA-Script you should not change `\parindent` and `\parskip` manually but use either option `parskip` (with suitable value, e.g., `parskip=half`) or command `\setparsizes`. Also you should usually use `\linespread` or package `setspace` instead of redefining `\baselineskip` or just remove the "redefinition", because you redefine it to its default.

Comment: I’ll look into this (and the `titlesec` ‘removal’) in a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually on one page is the chapter title shown, on the other page the section title in KOMA-Script.

To change this simply add

```
\automark[chapter]{chapter} % <============== usually \automark[section]{chapter}
```

in your preamble.

With the following complete code `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, chapterprefix=false, twoside]{scrbook}

% Packages
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in, left=1in, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}            % For font definition
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}    % For headers and footers (must be loaded before `titlesec`); also, in KomaScript, this is used instead of `titleps`
\usepackage{titlesec}            % For custom paragraph style of headings
\usepackage{lipsum}              % For Lorem Ipsum

% Global font family
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

% Global paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Part title format
\titleformat{\part}{\Huge\scshape\bfseries\centering}{}{0em}{}%

% Chapter title format
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}% For starting a chapter without page break

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{0pt}\Large\scshape\bfseries\centering}
    {\thesection\enspace}{0pt}{}[\vspace{2pt}{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}%
    {0mm}% How much of \titlerule line to remove from left
    {8mm}% Before \titlerule
    {0mm}% After \titlerule

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% This is to get rid of the chapter number

% Headers and footers
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark[chapter]{chapter} % <=========================================
\lefoot{\pagemark\quad\textsc{\headmark}}
\rofoot{\textsc{\headmark}\quad\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
    \part*{Test Part}

    \chapter*{Test Chapter or Whatever}%
    \chaptermark{Test Chapter}%

    \lipsum[1-14]

    \chapter*{Another Chapter to test}%
    \chaptermark{Another Chapter}%

    \lipsum[15-21]
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please note the warning you got in the `mwe.log` file:

> ```
> Class scrbook Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
> (scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
> (scrbook)              I'd suggest to use the package only
> (scrbook)              if you really need it, because it breaks several
> (scrbook)              KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
> (scrbook)              the extended optional argument of the section
> (scrbook)              commands.
> (scrbook)              Nevertheless, using requested
> (scrbook)              package `titlesec' on input line 10.
> ```

Comment: I noted the warning, read about it on bunch of sites, however, I was not able to reproduce the same thing with Koma-Script commands as with `titlesec`. The most basic thing I could not achive (yet) is to set a default font family (serif, sans and occassionally math) to Libertinus {Serif, Sans, Math}. At least, this works. :) Thank you. :)

Comment: @tukusejssirs Setting of the default font is done by `fontspec` not `titlesec` and `fontspec` can be used with KOMA-Script in the same way as with, e.g., the standard classes. To setup a font for a sectioning command you can use `\setkomafont`/`\addtokomafont` or `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. If you have problems in setting up the chapter/section headings with KOMA-Script please ask another question (if no one of [the already existing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bkoma-script%5D+AND+%5Bsectioning%5D) is suitable).

Comment: Thank you, @Schweinebacke, for the info. … Anyway, back to answer: I added `\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\scshape}` to change the font style from italics to small-caps regular.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `\automark{chapter}` and and replace `\headmark` by `\leftmark`. If more than one chapter starts on the same page the last chapter will set the mark for the footer even on odd pages.

```
\documentclass[10pt,
  headings=optiontohead% <- added
]{scrbook}
% Packages
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

% Global font family
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

% Global paragraph and line settings
\setparsizes{0pt}{0.08in}{0pt plus 1fil}

% Part title format
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{part}{\Huge\scshape}

% Chapter title format
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  beforeskip=\dimexpr8mm-\parskip\relax,
  afterskip=-\parskip,
  indent=0pt,
  font=\Large\scshape,
  afterindent=false,
  runin=false
]{chapter}

\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
  {\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{%
    \titlerule\par%
    \centering #3#4\par\kern-.75\ht\strutbox
    \titlerule%
  }}
  {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other sectioning levels
}
\newcommand\titlerule[1][1pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{#1}}

% Headers and footers
\clearpairofpagestyles% <- replaces deprecated command
\automark{chapter}
\lefoot{\pagemark\quad\textsc{\leftmark}}
\rofoot{\textsc{\leftmark}\quad\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\addpart*{Test Part}

\addchap[Test Chapter]{Test Chapter or Whatever}
\lipsum[1-14]

\addchap[Another Chapter]{Another Chapter to test}
\lipsum[15-21]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]